# How to call AsyncTask inside for loop in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am calling AsyncTask1 inside for loop at the same time need to call another AsyncTask2 in onPostExecute of AsyncTask1 . but i  am facing  something that . All AsyncTask1 Completed then only executing AsyncTask2. why? . can anyone tell me that how to do it.?﻿

Answer (score 0):

By default all async tasks go to the same queue (serial execution http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR).

If you want 2 async tasks execute in parallel use `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` or provide your own implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you are using the same instance to run it. Try an approach like this:

```
for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
    new AsyncTask()<Void, Void, Void>{
         //Your code here
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: This will not work. All async tasks will end up in one queue and wait for each other.